# Import a javascript function in js2py

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, backend

I have a python file:

```
import js2py
from js2py import require

js= '''
    function myfuntion(){
        var b = numar();
        return b;
    }
'''

a = js2py.eval_js(js)

print(a())
```

This is just an example. The "js2py" must call a function from a different javascript file.

The javascript file:

```
export function numar(){
    return 1; //return 1 if the checkbox is
}
```

How can I import that function into the js2py?

Comment: Will something like `js2py.translate_file('example.js', 'example.py')` match your use case?

Answer (score 3):

There is a new alternative to js2py called PythonMonkey which lets you import JavaScript files directly from Python and execute them.

https://github.com/Distributive-Network/PythonMonkey

JavaScript `numar.js` file:

```js
module.exports = function numar(){
    return 1; //return 1 if the checkbox is
}
```

Python `main.py` file:

```py
import pythonmonkey as pm
numar = pm.require('./numar')

print(numar()) # this outputs "1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue in js2py and this link may help you.
https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/issues/123#issuecomment-866218046

The only way to solve this is to modify translated file.

```
# translate myfunction.js, numar.js files to python
import js2py

js2py.translate_file('numar.js', 'numar.py')
js2py.translate_file('myfunction.js', 'myfunction.py')
```

```
// myfunction.js
var numar = require("./numar");
function myfunction() {
  var b = numar();
  return b;
}
```

```
// numar.js
function numar(){
    return 1; //return 1 if the checkbox is
}
```

```
# then modify translated myfunction.py file like this
__all__ = ['myfunction']

# Don't look below, you will not understand this Python code :) I don't.

from js2py.pyjs import *
from numar import numar
# setting scope
var = Scope( JS_BUILTINS )
set_global_object(var)

# Code follows:
var.registers(['numar', 'myfunction'])
@Js
def PyJsHoisted_myfunction_(this, arguments, var=var):
    var = Scope({'this':this, 'arguments':arguments}, var)
    var.registers(['b'])
    var.put('b', var.get('numar')())
    return var.get('b')
PyJsHoisted_myfunction_.func_name = 'myfunction'
var.put('myfunction', PyJsHoisted_myfunction_)
var.put('numar', numar.numar)
pass
pass


# Add lib to the module scope
myfunction = var.to_python()
```

```
# import in your code
from myfunction import myfunction

print(myfunction.myfunction())
```

You can find the code here.

https://github.com/lacmansoftware/python-js2py-require-solution